# How to remove horizontal lines around figures for htlatex output

Tags: floats, rules, tex4ht

htlatex adds horizontal lines around figures floats. For instance, the HTML output for the following tex:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{centering}
\includegraphics{photo.png}
\end{centering}
\end{figure}
```

is as follows:

```html
<hr class="figure">
<div class="figure">
<p class="noindent">
<img src="photo.png" alt="PIC" class="graphics" width="250pt" height="250pt">
<br/>
</div><hr class="endfigure">
```

I want to prevent automatic insertion of `<hr>`s around my figure. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: You can use CSS to select `hr.figure` and `hr.endfigure` then to fix property `display` to `none`: `hr.figure, hr.endfigure {display:none;}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way htlatex translates LaTeX environments and commands into HTML entities is configured by the file  `html4.4ht`.

On my Windows 7 computer using MikTeX, this file resides in the `%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht` directory.

You can provide your own configuration file when invoking htlatex. The rules
defined there overrule the standard configuration.

```
> htlatex myfile.tex "myfile.cfg,html"
```

The configuration file is a LaTeX file as described [here](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb25-1/gurari.pdf), for example.

Based on `html4.4ht`, I used the following configuration file `myfile.cfg`

```tex
\Preamble{html}
\begin{document}

% Removing div element surrounding tables and figures.
\ConfigureEnv{tabular}
    {\HCode{}}{\HCode{}}{}{}
\ConfigureEnv{figure} 
    {\HCode{}}{\HCode{}}{}{}    
% Always ignore \hline commands. Tables will rather be styled using CSS.
\Configure{hline}{\HCode{}}
% This one removes the rulers. Taking a look at html4.4ht should make 
% clear what has been changed.
\Configure{float}
   {\ifOption{refcaption}{}{\csname par\endcsname\ShowPar \leavevmode}}
   {\HCode{}}
{\ifvmode \IgnorePar \fi\EndP \HCode{}\csname par\endcsname\ShowPar}
\EndPreamble
```

Note that in order to remove HTML code that would otherwise being added, you have to use the `\HCode{}` command to generate an empty HTML output rather than just leaving the brackets empty.

Comment: I commented out the removal of \hline using `%\Configure{hline}{\HCode{}}`, since the tables didn't look very good.  Overall, thanks for the great answer on how to use a config file containing the pre-amble.